# Element automatic height

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1

I have this kind of element:

[image: Element]

Xaml:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="App1.CustomControls.ApplicationTile"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1.CustomControls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid x:Name="Grid">
    <Grid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF0353AE" Opacity="0.8"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border BorderThickness="0,3,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF023B7B" Opacity="0.8"/>
        </Border.BorderBrush>
        <Image Margin="14,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Source="../Assets/icn-download@2x.png"/>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="3,3,3,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF023B7B" Opacity="0.8"/>
        </Border.BorderBrush>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="0,3,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF023B7B" Opacity="0.8"/>
        </Border.BorderBrush>
        <Image Margin="14,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Source="../Assets/btn-training@2x.png"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

On my form i have a stack panel:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="TestStack"/>
```

My element stretches horizontaly, but i want it also to automattically stretch vertically, example:

Element is 200x200 px, so if stack panel is 1000px width, than element resizes to 1000x1000px

How to achieve this?

I could do it like:

```
CustomElement CE = new CustomElement();
CE.Heigth = TestStack.Width; //But width isn't set, because it is HorizontalAligment=Stretch
```

Comment: Have you tried `TestStack.ActualWidth` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this adding a SizeChanged event to my UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUserControl"
 SizeChanged="UserControl_SizeChanged">
<!-- ... -->
```

and setting Height while changing the Width.

```
private void UserControl_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Math.Abs(e.NewSize.Width - e.PreviousSize.Width) > 0)
        Height = e.NewSize.Width;
}
```